size=x' data error - 2 rows in data but 1 row heights
I get the following error when trying to upload an image and load it in a pdf with xhtml2pdf with a template, when viewing it in the admin it appears correct, but in the pdf it gives me the error
ValueError at /multas/ <PmlTable@0x1F3B48B4320 2 rows x 1 cols> with cell(0,0) containing <PmlKeepInFrame at 0x1f3b48b4680> size=x data error - 2 rows in data but 1 row heights
Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/multas/?id=33 Django Version: 3.2 Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value:     <PmlTable@0x1F3B48B4320 2 rows x 1 cols> with cell(0,0) containing '<PmlKeepInFrame at 0x1f3b48b4680> size=x' data error - 2 rows in data but 1 row heights Exception Location: C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\simertg\venv\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\tables.py, line 319, in __init__ Python Executable:  C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\simertg\venv\Scripts\python.exe Python Version: 3.12.2
enter image description here

Unfortunately the error information does not include a line number or block id which would help to identify where the actual error occurred.
All I can recommend is to check that your table header rows match the number of detail rows.
I got a similar error when I tried to use additional table rows for spacing in my heading.
<tr/tr>
     <tr><td style="font-size:xx-large; color: #1866a0 ; text-align:justify ; ">{{plan.name}}</></td></tr>
<tr/tr>

when I removed the additional "tr's" the code converted correctly
